# Android Google Maps API turn-by-turn режим

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Возможно ли включить в Google Map режим сопровождения от точки до точки.
Как в навигаторах, чтобы камера крутилась в зависимости от движения.

Толком ничего не смог найти на эту тему.